# SQL case condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a hard time to select the duration
WHEN state is 1 or WHEN state is 4

How can i query it?

[image]

Comment: `SELECT duration from yourTable WHERE state IN (1, 4)` ... was that so hard?

Comment: `select duration from your_table where state = 1 or state = 4`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select multiple values in WHERE clause:

```
SELECT duration
FROM <Table_Name>
WHERE state in (1, 4)
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually you would need a WHERE subquery with the OR operator to do that:

```
SELECT Duration FROM tablename WHERE State = 1 OR State = 4
```